# Vanilla JS+AJAX - check whether a value already exists

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've got a form, which contains an input (a title for a post). I need that input to be filled with a value that doesn't exiest already in my database, so what I'm trying to do is requesting an AJAX call, to check on the fly whether that post title is already created, activated by "onChange" event.

Here is my Vanilla JS\AJAX code:

```
            function checkEx(url, cFunction) {
                var xhttp;
                xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        cFunction(this);
                    }
                };
                xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
                xhttp.send();

            }

            function checkExNow(xhttp) {
                document.getElementById("pcp_ex").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            }
```

And here is my HTML input:

```
<input onchange="checkEx('inc/ajax/pcp_check_ex_value.php', checkExNow)" name="pcp_name" type="text" placeholder="Post Title"> <div id="pcp_ex"></div>
```

Problem is, I have to find a way to send the input's value, in order to check it with my database on that PHP file.

Please, teach me how to do this using vanilla JS.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: And what exactly are you having problems with? Reading the input value via the DOM API? Adding the value to the URL? How to make a POST request instead? You should be able to find existing solutions to all these problems. Or is it something else?

Comment: One way to get the value is `document.querySelector('input[name=pcp_name]').value`

Comment: Thank you guys. I'm sorry if my question is dumb (is this why people downvoted my question?). I'm very new to AJAX, to say at least.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also send to your function the current value of the input field

```
function checkEx(url, cFunction, valueToCheck) {
    var xhttp;
    xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            cFunction(this);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", url+"?check="+valueToCheck, true);
    xhttp.send();
}

<input onchange="checkEx('inc/ajax/pcp_check_ex_value.php', checkExNow, this.value)" name="pcp_name" type="text" placeholder="Post Title"> <div id="pcp_ex"></div>
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange2) you could check a complete example.

Comment: Thank you Lucas. i'm a bit confused - how should I handle it on the PHP side? how should I "detect" the data?

Comment: i'm sorry for asking again, but what if I need to send an upload input? I tried POST, FILES, and google'd as well but found out nothing in plain JS. i'll be thankful for help one more time. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your help, I managed.
For those who reached that post with similar issue, wondering how to do this, this is how I managed:

JS:

```
            function checkEx(url, cFunction, valueToCheck) {
                var xhttp;
                xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        cFunction(this);
                    }
                };
                xhttp.open("GET", url+"?check="+valueToCheck, true);
                xhttp.send();
            }

            function checkExNow(xhttp) {

                document.getElementById("pcp_ex").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            }
```

HTML:

```
 <input onchange="checkEx('inc/ajax/pcp_check_ex_value.php', checkExNow, this.value)" name="pcp_name" class="reg_input" type="text" placeholder="Post Title"> 
<span id="pcp_ex"></span>
```

PHP:

```
$exe = $_GET['check'];
```